# ArcGIS Server Rest API date issue

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, oracle-spatial, map-service, date

I am using "date '2015-8-10'" in ArcGIS Server REST API to retreive records from map services. But it returns the error "Fail to Execute". My date is stored as "10-AUG-15".

When it is in the right date format, as it is stored in map service, it returns an accurate result. It is not matching the Esri date format with date format in the attribute table of Map service. Column type is also specified as date in the Map service attribute table.

Do I need to make some changes in ArcGIS for Server to convert the Esri date format to my stored format?

I am using Oracle Spatial feature class in ArcMap and then creating map service on ArcGIS Server. Type of column that contains dates is also date in the Oracle table.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to clarify your data storage technology behind the feature class, and the native datatype in which the dates are being stored. It is always unwise to format date strings without leading zeroes.

Comment: SQL queries use the native database date formatting function. You are using Microsoft syntax.

Comment: how can i resolve that issue ??

Comment: Google "oracle date formatting functions"